# Use liquibase with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, liquibase

I try to use `liquibase` with `nodejs`.
For this, I use the npm package `liquibase`, and I'm using my localhost SQL database. I've also downloaded `Java` in my local machine.

This is what I've tried:

```
const path = require('path');

const liquibase = require('liquibase');

let db;

(async () => {
    try {
        await liquibase({
            liquibase: path.join(__dirname, 'liquibase/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar'),
            classpath: path.join(__dirname, 'liquibase/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar'),
            changeLogFile: path.join(__dirname, 'liquibase/resource/inmates_1.sql'),
            url: 'localhost',
            username: 'root',
            password: '',
        }).run('update');
        console.log('Liquibase set up successfully.');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(`Liquibase error: ${e}.`);
    }
})();
```

When I try to run this I get error:

```
Liquibase error: Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Tal\Desktop\mysql_test\liquibase\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar --changeLogFile=C:\Users\Tal\Desktop\mysql_test\liquibase\resource\inmates_1.sql --url=localhost --username=root --password= --classpath=C:\Users\Tal\Desktop\mysql_test\liquibase\postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar update
```

**important: I DONT HAVE ANY OTHER FILES EXCEPT FOR THOSE IN THE CODE**

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your --url argument looks wrong:
--url=localhost

In [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) proper format of the url arg will be a JDBC string. For an oracle example:

> url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.22:1521/orcl

It would be helpful to see the whole log as well, it may be easier to post questions and upload files on the [Liquibase forum](https://forum.liquibase.org/) itself.